# what is DIA EDM Reference modal and how can we use it with sharepoint?

Tags: document-library

We need something to connect metadata with document library. My senior suggest me DIA EDM Reference modal. But I can't find any related information to it. can any one please tell me what is DIA EDM Reference modal and how can we use it with SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a metadata model for Electronic Document Management (EDM) specifically for biopharmaceuticals.

Details can be found here: http://www.diaglobal.org/zh-CN/News-and-Publications/Publications-and-Research/EDM-Corner.aspx

With some work you should be able to set this up as managed metadata.